# Python - Beautiful Soup - Remove Tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have extracted the below web based data as a list using `Beautiful Soup`. On the original website it's a table of numbers:

```
[<td class="right">113</td>, <td class="right">
 89 </td>, <td class="right last">
<b>117</b> </td>, <td class="right">113</td>, <td class="right">
 85 </td>, <td class="right last">
<b>114</b> </td>, <td class="right">100</td>, <td class="right">
 56 </td>, <td class="right last">
<b>84</b> </td>]
```

What's the most efficient way to create a list of numbers from this data? Ideally I'd like to extract the tags using Beautiful Soup but I can't figure out how to do this from the documentation.

My original Soup code is:

```
print soup.find_all('td', 'right')             #printing this produces the above data

numbers_data = []                              #my attempt to extract tags
for e in soup.find_all('td', 'right'):
    numbers_data.append(e.extract())

print numbers_data
```

Both return the same list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
numbers_data = [int(e.text) for e in soup.find_all('td', 'right')]

print numbers_data
```

Comment: Isn't it `e.string` or `e.get_text()` rather than `e.text`?

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper - No. BeautifulSoup has a text property on a node.

As an aside, if you're using BeautifulSoup4 - Use css syntax selectors, much cleaner - ```soup.select('td.right')```

Comment: they seem to be the same: `e = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<a href="#">hi<h1>c</h1></a>'); print(e.text); print(e.get_text())`

Comment: @DivinusVox - curious, I can't find `text` as an attribute in the docs.  If it works, it works, but I wonder if it might be falling through to the underlying parser?  (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string and the `strings` and `stripped_strings` generators are what I see documented).

Comment: It's true, `.text` is an undocumented feature. I don't use `BeautifulSoup` frequently enough to remember all the names, so I'm forever getting it wrong and using `.text` when I mean `.string`.

Comment: @SteveJessop - and going source-diving, it looks like `.text` is a property that's implemented by calling `get_text` with its default arguments.  Interesting.