# Extract information from html tags using beautiful soup python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url='https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/london/west-wickham/?q=West%20Wickham%2C%20London&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=home'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html,'html.parser')

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"listing-results-wrapper"}) 

listing_price = []
listing_nobed = []

for c in containers:
    listing_price.append(c.findAll("a",{"class":"listing-results-price text-price"}))
    listing_nobed.append(c.findAll("h3",{"class":"listing-results-attr"}))

print(listing_price[0])
print('----------------------------')
print(listing_nobed[0])
```

results:

```
[<a class="listing-results-price text-price" href="/for-sale/details/50924268">




        £500,000







                <span class="price-modifier">Offers over</span>
</a>]
----------------------------
[<h3 class="listing-results-attr">
<span class="num-icon num-beds" title="3 bedrooms"><span class="interface"></span>3</span> <span class="num-icon num-baths" title="1 bathroom"><span class="interface"></span>1</span> <span class="num-icon num-reception" title="2 reception rooms"><span class="interface"></span>2</span>
</h3>]
```

I want:

```
Price   NoBeds NoBaths NoRec
500,000 3      1       2
xxx     x      x       NaN
```

Where xxx is the price, etc. Some of the values do not have a tag, so if that is the case, then show NaN or 0

I tried [Python - Beautiful Soup - Remove Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016427/python-beautiful-soup-remove-tags) to to extract the (3,1,2) values to no avail.

To extract the price, I thought of using regex, but found many comments here do not recommend it.

I am still trying to understand html tags and data extractions, so any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for the [.string](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) attribute of the tag? rather than appending the entire tag it looks like you only inted to extract the text itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `next()` to find any next elements and for cleaning `text()` `strip()`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
my_url='https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/london/west-wickham/?q=West%20Wickham%2C%20London&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=home'

req = requests.get(my_url)
page_soup = soup(req.content,'html.parser')

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"listing-results-wrapper"}) 

for c in containers:
    a = c.find("a",{"class":"listing-results-price text-price"})
    b = c.find("h3",{"class":"listing-results-attr"})

    NoBedsx = b.find('span',{'class':'num-icon num-beds'})
    NoBathsx = b.find('span',{'class':'num-icon num-baths'})
    NoRecx = b.find('span',{'class':'num-icon num-reception'})

    if a:
        Price = a.next.strip().encode('utf-8')
    if NoBedsx:
        NoBeds = NoBedsx.next.next.encode('utf-8')
    if NoBathsx:
        NoBaths = NoBathsx.next.next.encode('utf-8')
    if NoRecx:
        NoRec = NoRecx.next.next.encode('utf-8')
    print('{} {} {} {}'.format(Price,NoBeds,NoBaths,NoRec))
```

Output:

```
Price  NoBeds NoBaths NoRec
£500,000 3 1 2
£337,500 4 2 1
£875,000 5 2 2
£695,000 4 1 2
£190,000 1 1 1
£670,000 4 2 1
£610,000 3 2 2
£675,000 4 2 1
£580,000 4 2 1
£850,000 5 2 1
£185,000 1 2 1
£760,000 5 2 1
£675,000 3 2 1
£142,000 1 2 1
£550,000 2 2 1
£817,000 4 2 1
£139,000 1 2 1
£625,000 3 1 2
£145,000 1 1 2
£725,000 4 1 2
£799,995 4 1 2
£575,000 3 1 2
£465,000 3 1 2
£725,000 4 2 2
£465,000 4 2 2
```

Comment: Love it! Thanks!!